# Laravel eloquent response conversion on the fly without foreach loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this is my function:

```
public function listAllItems() {
  return $item = Item::with('taxes', 'quantities')->first();
}
```

Response:

```
{
"name": "TARGUS LAPTOP BAG",
"category": "BAG",
"subcategory": "LAPTOP BACKPACK",
"brand": "TARGUS",
"item_number": "236550364000001",
"description": "",
"cost_price": "0.00",
"unit_price": "6999.00",
"reorder_level": "1.000",
"item_id": 1,
"deleted": 0,
"taxes": [
{
"item_id": 1,
"name": "CGST",
"percent": "9.0"
},
{
"item_id": 1,
"name": "SGST",
"percent": "9.0"
}
],
"quantities": [
{
 "item_id": 1,
 "location_id": 5,
 "quantity": 0
},
{
 "item_id": 1,
 "location_id": 6,
 "quantity": 0
}
]
}
```

Now if we look at the inner objects of taxes and quantities. I had to access them using indexes. How can I use the 'name' (in case of taxes) as key of the object and 'percent' as the value.

I want to fetch entire item's details as shown in the question but the taxes and quantities should be as key:value based on inner fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$taxes = $item->taxes->pluck('percent', 'name');
$quantities = $item->quantities->pluck('percent', 'name');
```

Comment: I want to fetch entire item's details as shown in the question but the taxes and quantities should be as key:value based on inner fields.

Comment: if you are looking for pair with Primary column then it's possible either it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

Several ways you could approach this, personally I would use a transformer to create the final output array. Laravel's [JsonResource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) class is a made for this kind of data manipulation.

Alternatively, you can manually map and merge the item and target collections, for example:

```
$item = Item::with('taxes', 'quantities')->first();

$taxes = array_reduce($item->taxes, function ($taxes, $tax) {
    return data_set($taxes, $tax->name, $tax->percent);
}, []);

$quantities = array_reduce($item->quantities, function ($quantities, $quantity) {
    return data_set($quantities, $quantity->name, $quantity->quantity);
}, []);

$arr = array_merge($item->attributesToArray(), $taxes, $quantities);
```